# Last two lines of a file are same means trigger e-mail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

```
2016-11-04 13:49:03,055 [http] INFO : Start Outputing Report: Project ID:c_cathnic_day_16843, Format:HTML, Locale: en_US

2016-11-04 13:49:03,715 [http] INFO : Finished Outputing Report: Project ID:c_cathnic_day_16843, Format:HTML, Locale: en_US

2016-11-04 13:49:47,094 [http] INFO : Start Outputing Report: Project ID:c_begtypie_16843, Format:HTML, Locale: en_US

2016-11-04 13:49:49,519 [http] INFO : Finished Outputing Report: Project ID:c_begtypie_16843, Format:HTML, Locale: en_US
```

Above is my log file.

I want to get triggered by an e-mail if I get the last two lines as,

```
2016-11-04 13:49:47,094 [http] INFO : Start Outputing Report: Project ID:c_begtypie_16843, Format:HTML, Locale: en_US

2016-11-04 13:49:47,094 [http] INFO : Start Outputing Report: Project ID:c_begtypie_16843, Format:HTML, Locale: en_US
```

It means, if two reports are in line, I have to get triggered.

Is it possible using awk utility?
Or How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[ $(tail -n 2 file | uniq | wc -l) -eq 1 ]] && sendmail
```

Or if there are blank lines as in your input file:

```
[[ $(tail -n 4 file | sort | uniq | wc -l) -eq 2 ]] && sendmail
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `tac` to read the last 2 lines:

```
tac file | {
    read last_line
    read penultimate_line
    if [[ "$list_line" = "$penultimate_line" ]]; then
        send_email
    fi
}
```

Using pipes places the commands in subshells, so I've used grouping parentheses to perform multiple commands without losing the variables.

With awk, you'd write:

```
awk '
    {previous_line = last_line; last_line = $0} 
    END {
        if (previous_line == last_line) {
            send_email
        }
    }
' file
```